# Need regular expression to search and use that search result in replacement regular expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ search/replace feature. I need regular expression to search and use that search result in replacement regular expression. The solution should work for any token, "\" or "today" or anything. Let me better explain with examples:

1. Example #1: `//Comment`
   After matching regular expression & substituting, the replaced result is: `// Comment`
2. Example #2: `todayis`
   After matching regular expression & substituting, the replaced result is: `today is`
3. Example: #3: `todayon`
   After matching regular expression & substituting, the replaced result is: `today on`

So I use a regular expression like this for Search: `today[a-z]`

Replace: today `$&[a-z]`

but it does nor work. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

In Notepad++ you can find with:

```
\btoday\K(?=[a-z])
```

**Explanation**

- `\btoday` A word boundary, then match `today`
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `(?=[a-z])` Assert a-z directly to the right of the current position

In the replacement use a space.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ovK22M/1)

[image]

---

Or using the `$&` to use the full match, you can find with:

```
\btoday(?=[a-z])
```

And then use `$&`  in the replacement.

**Edit**

For both replacements you can use this pattern with an alternation matching either `//` or `today`, and replace with a space:

```
(?:\btoday|//)\K(?=[a-zA-Z])
```

Comment: he could also use a backreference with something like `"todayis".replaceAll("((?:is)|(?:on))", " $1")`

Comment: @el_chupacabra It would be like this `(?:is|on)` without needing the capture group, but the OP wants to match `today`

Comment: But it does not work if it's something like this "//comment". This should be "
// comment" or "//today" should be "// today". How would you update that regular expression to do that?

Comment: @code4u But that is not in the question, you are specifically searching for `today` What exactly do you want to accomplish? What is the "rule" that you want to introduce?

Comment: @Thefourthbird maybe  "todayis".replaceAll("today((?:is)|(?:on))", "today $1") then? Anyway I suspect op is looking for backtracking here, but it is not a very well put question over all

Comment: @Thefourthbird That is the question. That token can be "today" or can be the Java comment symbol "//". The solution provided does not work when the token is "//" . Can someone write a solution for   "//comment" should be  "// comment" ?

Comment: @code4u Do you mean like this? `(?:\btoday|//)\K(?=[a-zA-Z])` https://regex101.com/r/PSocZE/1